# Android Wear - Connect to IP Address

Tags: wear-os

I already did some research on Android Wear. It seems not possible to connect to an concrete IP Adress from an Wear Device without using the Phone as a proxy.
I understand that this is because of battery life, but in my case i do not really care about battery life. Anyone got a connection without using the phone as a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your watch is not connected directly to a phone (via BT), and if your watch supports wifi and it is turned on, then you can make direct network calls from your watch.

Comment: Do you have any little sample for that ? because i always stumple over the Data APIs which seem to need the ID of the wearable. I need a simple HTTP Call to some IP adress as usual.

Comment: If WiFi is up on your watch, there is no difference between making a HTTP call on the watch or phone, use any Http Client that you are familiar with. Make sure you have added the internet permissions to your manifest and make sure you check that wifi is up.